# Add field to objects in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` called "news"

This array contains a lot of information.

news:

```
{
    Altitude = 0;
    BeschreibungApp = "Heuriger Zum Poysdorfer, 2170 Poysdorf";
    ID = 17922;
    Icon = Weintraube;
    Latitude = "48.67063";
    Link = "http://heurigenapp.nocache.gugler.at/app.php?id=17922";
    Longitude = "16.62858";
    Name = "Heuriger Zum Poysdorfer";
    Ort = Poysdorf;
},
{
    Altitude = 0;
    BeschreibungApp = "Heuriger Grazerberg-Schenke, 2170 Poysdorf";
    ID = 17923;
    Icon = Weintraube;
    Latitude = "48.66929";
    Link = "http://heurigenapp.nocache.gugler.at/app.php?id=17923";
    Longitude = "16.61484";
    Name = "Heuriger Grazerberg-Schenke";
    Ort = Poysdorf;
},
{
    Altitude = 0;
    BeschreibungApp = "Kruspel - Top Heuriger, Buschenschank Kruspel, 2070 Unternalb";
    ID = 18040;
    Icon = Weintraube;
    Latitude = "48.73728";
    Link = "http://heurigenapp.nocache.gugler.at/app.php?id=18040";
    Longitude = "15.96020";
    Name = "Kruspel - Top Heuriger, Buschenschank Kruspel";
    Ort = Unternalb;
}
```

In my app for iPhone, I show the distance from my current location to the destination.
I already have the result in a string.

Can I add this string to my array?
So that I have Altitude, BeschreibungApp, Icon, Latitude, Link, Longitude, Name, Ort, and Distance.

Comment: Does the array contain NSMutableDictionary objects?

Answer (score 0):

Are those values just stored as strings? It seems to me like you would want to be using a NSMutableDictionary to store the key and value. If that isn't the case - NSArray is immutable and can not be changed (short of destroying and recreating it). Use a NSMutableArray and then [yourArray addObject:distanceObject];

Either way - in order to change the NSArray in needs to be mutable.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer! Is there a way to change my array into a mutableArray?

Comment: @theandrew Make a `mutableCopy` of it.

Comment: NSMutableArray *newArray = [news mutableCopy]; This way?

Answer (score 0):

An NSArray contains objects. Thus I assume that the entries in your array are instances of some class. So, if your class does not have an instance variable that can store the new string, it is not possible to store it additionally.
I suggest to define such a new instance variable in this class. If (a pointer to) an object (an instance of this class) is stored in your array, it is possible to store the new string in an instance of this class, and thus in your array.

Comment: sorry but i don't exactly what you mean. Can you explain it to me? because i haven't a lot of experience yet.

Comment: Well, an NSArray is immutable (in contrast to an NSMutableArray). But this relates only to the values that are stored in the array. So if you have stored 3 "objects" in yours array, as in your example, it is not possible to add another one, or to delete one. But in your array are only stored LINKS to your objects. It is still possible to modify the objects. So if the object (an instance of your class) can store the string, you can insert this string into an instance of your class without changing your array. Hope this helps...

Comment: i already have my made NSMutableArray. But know i want to add the "Distance"! Do you have an idea how i can do this?

Comment: You can only add objects to an NSMutableArray, not e.g. floats. So if "Distance" is a class, and you instantiated it, you can add the instance using the addObject: method.